# Problem with stepper motor not landing on same spot

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, accuracy

I had a quick question regarding a stepper motor that I'm working with. I am running the 5 pin, 5V motor via an Arduino board and using the sketches provided. I am trying to get the motor to rotate in full circles broken up into small segments and although it is working (currently I have 7 'stops')I can't seem to get the stops where the motor stops to overlap. There's always a slight change that throws everything off. Any ideas?

```
/* 
Stepper Motor Control - one revolution

This program drives a unipolar or bipolar stepper motor. 
The motor is attached to digital pins 8 - 11 of the Arduino.

The motor should revolve one revolution in one direction, then
one revolution in the other direction.  


Created 11 Mar. 2007
Modified 30 Nov. 2009
by Tom Igoe

*/

#include <Stepper.h> 

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per                                 revolution
                                 // for your motor

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8,9,10,11);    
int stepCount = 0;  // number of steps the motor has taken

void setup() {
// set the speed at 60 rpm:
myStepper.setSpeed(60);
// initialize the serial port:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
// read the sensor value:
int sensorReading = analogRead(A0);
// map it to a range from 0 to 100:
int motorSpeed = map(sensorReading, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
// set the motor speed:
if (motorSpeed > 0) {
myStepper.setSpeed(motorSpeed);
// step 1/100 of a revolution:
myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution/100);
} 
// step one revolution  in one direction:
Serial.println("clockwise");
myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
delay(500);

// step one revolution in the other direction:
Serial.println("counterclockwise");
myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
delay(500); 
}
```

Comment: Use an absolute position encoder. Then even a DC motor will work.

Answer (score 4):

Slow the system way down.  If inertia is a problem then the system will probably seek correctly.  If the problem persists it is more likely the problem is in the software.

Answer (score 3):

If the code does everything right (I'm not an expert on that), there is the chance of your motor "losing" steps. There are a number of reasons why this can happen: Accelerate or stop too fast (allow some time to account for the mechanical inertia!), use too little torque (proportional to motor current), or have the motor turn at the speed where it resonates.

You can compare a stepper's rotor to a mechanical pendulum being held in place by springs, the equivalent of the springs being the magnetic force holding the rotor in place.

Such a mass-spring-system has a resonant frequency. For a stepper, it's usually quite low and the resoncance occurs at low speeds. Therefore, when accelerating or stopping a stepper, you want to get over the speed of resonance quite fast and not remain there for an extended time. Any load (including gear) attached to the motor will of course alter the resonant frequency.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Zebonaut's post, we have also seen more esoteric behaviour driving steppers:

- Stepper driver chips (Allegro A4983) which miss microsteps (they basically admitted it in the A4988 data-sheet)
- Microprocessor timer pins which do not reliably toggle, or which bounce... we ended up manually reading the pin state just to confirm
- Maths or programming/counting errors when changing direction or working out the number of steps between two points, it's very easy to be 1 step (or microstep) out when you stop, start, or change direction.
- Motors losing (microstep) position when putting the driver IC into low-power mode when stationary.